# how can I create a custom object from using values from another object's elements?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I got stuck in a problem where I want to create objects of my own choice from entries from other objects.

Here is what I want to say

I created an object like this -

```js
{FY13: Array(12), FY14: Array(12), FY15: Array(12)}

and each Array(12) contains 12 months value
0: {DECEMBER: 305613430.7701738}
1: {JANUARY: 275987392.27062917}
2: {FEBRUARY: 233681429.7241771}
3: {MARCH: 276556599.762852}
4: {APRIL: 291581891.6168785}
5: {MAY: 243244065.40839994}
6: {JUNE: 251725888.83152565}
7: {JULY: 263685518.35567823}
8: {AUGUST: 255451062.8538219}
9: {SEPTEMBER: 401511405.31539994}
10: {OCTOBER: 278446608.78520465}
11: {NOVEMBER: 346733805.9584188}
```

I want to make another objects from each entries from this object and create a new one like this-

```js
{
FY13{
  'Q1-FY-13': 305613430.7701738+275987392.27062917+233681429.7241771,
  'Q2-FY-13': 276556599.762852+ 291581891.6168785+243244065.40839994,
  'Q3-FY-13': val of other months....',
  'Q4-FY-13': ''
},
FY14{
  'Q1-FY-13': ...,
  'Q2-FY-13': ...,
  'Q3-FY-13': ...,
  'Q4-FY-13': ....,
},
FY15{
  'Q1-FY-13': ...,
  'Q2-FY-13': ...,
  'Q3-FY-13': ...,
  'Q4-FY-13': ....,
}
}
```

This is waht I have done so far-
I grouped by the objects according to year and store them in an array and it is totally hardcoded -

```js
let objectArray = [...this.totalObject];

      let groupByYear = objectArray.reduce(function(acc, obj) {
        var key = obj["Year"].trim();

        acc[key] = acc[key] || [];

        acc[key].push({
          [obj.Month.trim().toUpperCase()]: obj.value
        });
        return acc;
      }, {});

      console.log("Group By Year", groupByYear);
      let dataArray = [];
      for (let key in groupByYear) {
        let val = groupByYear[key];
        let obj1 = {
          ["Q1_" + key]: [val[0].DECEMBER + val[1].JANUARY + val[2].FEBRUARY]
        };
        dataArray.push(obj1)
        let obj2 = {
          ["Q2_" + key]: [val[3].MARCH + val[4].APRIL + val[5].MAY]
        };
        dataArray.push(obj2)
        let obj3 = {
          ["Q3_" + key]: [val[6].JUNE + val[7].JULY + val[8].AUGUST]
        };
        dataArray.push(obj3)
        let obj4 = {
          ["Q4_" + key]: [val[9].SEPTEMBER + val[10].OCTOBER + val[11].NOVEMBER]
        };
        dataArray.push(obj4)
      }
      console.log('Data Array',dataArray);
```

It is giving me the same output but i want this to be flexible- any alternative way?

```js
0: {Q1_FY13: Array(1)}
1: {Q2_FY13: Array(1)}
2: {Q3_FY13: Array(1)}
3: {Q4_FY13: Array(1)}
4: {Q1_FY14: Array(1)}
5: {Q2_FY14: Array(1)}
6: {Q3_FY14: Array(1)}
7: {Q4_FY14: Array(1)}
8: {Q1_FY15: Array(1)}
9: {Q2_FY15: Array(1)}
10: {Q3_FY15: Array(1)}
11: {Q4_FY15: Array(1)}
```

Thank you for your time here. I am noob in using Higher order function so if any real heck is there please do mention.

Comment: Do you have control over the input data? The `{FY13: Array(12), FY14: Array(12), FY15: Array(12)}` and the arrays? Meaning, did you create those by yourself from another data source?

Comment: Does the fiscal year start in December, and that’s why DECEMBER is the first element in the array? Or is that just a random coincidence?

Comment: @AndreasPizsa - Yes I have control over the data.The actual Data I am getting is in this format:
  0:  {Channel: "XXXX", Su: "               Gross Sales (4000)", Month: "     December", Year: "FY13", temp: "Actual", …}
1: {Channel: "YYYY", Su: "               Gross Sales (4000)", Month: "     December", Year: "FY14", temp: "Actual", …}
2: {Channel: "ZZZ", Su: "               Gross Sales (4000)", Month: "     December", Year: "FY15", temp: "Actual", …}.......



Yes the fiscal year start in DECEMBER

Comment: Can you clean up the input data so that it’s `[[2013, [4000, 5000, 6000, ...], [2014, [89882, ...]]]` - in other words, where each year is an array where the first element is the fiscal year number, and the second element is an array of monthly revenues, starting with the first month of the fiscal year.

Getting this right will make processing _a lot_ easier going forward.

If you need help with that, I suggest posting a separate question (and a link to that question here)

Answer (score 0):

let's go step by step,

1) Declare necessary var

```
var arr = [{"DECEMBER":305613430.7701738},{"JANUARY":275987392.27062917},{"FEBRUARY":233681429.7241771},{"MARCH":276556599.762852},{"APRIL":291581891.6168785},{"MAY":243244065.40839994},{"JUNE":251725888.83152565},{"JULY":263685518.35567823},{"AUGUST":255451062.8538219},{"SEPTEMBER":401511405.31539994},{"OCTOBER":278446608.78520465},{"NOVEMBER":346733805.9584188}];

var quarters = {
q1: ['DECEMBER', "JANUARY", "FEBRUARY"],
q2: ['APRIL', "MAY","MARCH"],
q3: [ "JUNE" ,"JULY", "AUGUST"],
q4: [ "SEPTEMBER" ,"OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER"]
}

var FY ={ FY12: arr, FY13: arr}
```

2) get Final results

```
    var result = Object.keys(FY).reduce((acc, fy)=> {
        acc[fy] = Object.keys(quarters).reduce((accq, q) => {
            accq[`${q}-${fy}`] = FY[fy].map(f => {return quarters[q].indexOf(Object.keys(f)[0]) > -1 ? Object.values(f)[0]: null})
                                       .filter(x=>x)  //remove false values
                                      .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) ; // sum
            return accq;
        }, {})
    return acc;
    }, {})

    console.log(result)
```

Comment: var FY ={ FY12: arr, FY13: arr} 
This line is not dynamic right? we have to specify every time seperately. If suppose the year gets changed to FY17, FY18 and FY19 then>?

Comment: it will work as it is. Here we need keys only to specify `quarters` . e.g. if `FY` has keys like `FY17, FY18` and so on then `quarters ` will be `q1-FY17, .... q1-FY18`